# Magento2: difference between layout/default.xml and page_layout/1column.xml

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to learn Magento2 and created a new theme. Now I seem to be unable to grasp the difference, or rather: the purpose, of the layout/default.xml and the page_layout xml files.

What I did was prepare my page layout in layout.xml and I modified the main.content container in default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="section" htmlClass="main" htmlId="main"/>
```

Now I thought I'd modify the 1column.xml so that the class of main.content is different:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper"> ... </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlClass="main col-1"/>
</layout>
```

But the main.content section still does have the class "main" only. Why does this not work?